# Locating SubArray in ByteArray

Tags: c#, search, buffer, streamreader, indexof

**SUMMARY**

in reading bytes from a file in chunks(not got a specific size between 128 - 1024, haven't decided yet) and i want to search the buffer to see if it contains a signature(pattern) of another byte array, and if it finds some of the pattern at the very end of the buffer it should read the next few bytes from the files to see if its found a match

**What I've Tried**

```cs
public static bool Contains(byte[] buffer, byte[] signiture, FileStream file)
{
    for (var i = buffer.Length - 1; i >= signiture.Length - 1; i--) //move backwards through array stop if < signature
    {
        var found = true; //set found to true at start
        for (var j = signiture.Length - 1; j >= 0 && found; j--) //loop backwards throughsignature
        {
            found = buffer[i - (signiture.Length - 1 - j)] == signiture[j];// compare signature's element with corresponding element of buffer
        }
        if (found)
            return true; //if signature is found return true
    }


    //checking end of buffer for partial signiture
    for (var x = signiture.Length - 1; x >= 1; x--)
    {
        if (buffer.Skip(buffer.Length - x).Take(x).SequenceEqual(signiture.Skip(0).Take(x))) //check if partial is equal to partial signiture
        {
            byte[] nextBytes = new byte[signiture.Length - x];
            file.Read(nextBytes, 0, signiture.Length - x); //read next needed bytes from file
            if (!signiture.Skip(0).Take(x).ToArray().Concat(nextBytes).SequenceEqual(signiture))
                return false; //return false if not a match
            return true; //return true if a match
        }
    }
    return false; //if not found return false
}
```

This works but I've been told linq is slow and that i should use Array.IndexOf(). I've tried that but cant figure out how to implement it

Comment: Linq can take a lot of memory which will make some queries run slow.  If you are just running data on a small array is will probably run faster in linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Span<T>,` `AsSpan` and [`MemoryExtensions.SequenceEqual`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.sequenceequal&ved=2ahUKEwjCk7O-87_pAhXInOAKHQ_GAs4QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2sJAtxaR7vaaf1fdh7P3N4&cshid=1589892015433). The latter is not LINQ; it is optimized, especially for byte arrays. It unrolls the loop and uses unsafe code to essentially do a `memcmp`.

If you aren't using a framework that includes these types/methods by default, (.Netcore2.1+,. Netstandard 2.1) you can add the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) nuget package. The implementation of `SequenceEqual` is a bit different (the so-called "slow version") but it is still faster than using LINQ's `SequenceEqual`.

Note that you also need to check the return value of `FileStream.Read`.

```
public static bool Contains(byte[] buffer, byte[] signiture, FileStream file)
{
    var sigSpan = signiture.AsSpan();

    //move backwards through buffer and check if signature found
    for (var i = buffer.Length - signiture.Length; i >= 0; i--)
    { 
        if (buffer.AsSpan(i, signiture.Length).SequenceEqual(sigSpan))
            return true;
    }

    for (var x = signiture.Length - 1; x >= 1; x--)
    {
        var sig = sigSpan.Slice(0, x);
        if (buffer.AsSpan(buffer.Length - x).SequenceEqual(sig)) //check if partial is equal to partial signiture
        {
            var sigLen = signiture.Length;
            byte[] nextBytes = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(sigLen - x);

            // need to store number of bytes read
            var read = file.Read(nextBytes, 0, sigLen - x); //read next needed bytes from file
            var next = nextBytes.AsSpan(0, read);

            // don't need to concat with signature, because obviously signature is going to 
            // start with signature.Skip(0).Take(...)
            // just test that the number of bytes we read, plus the number we will skip equals
            // the actual length, then check the remainder
            var result = (read + x == signiture.Length 
                       && signiture.AsSpan(x).SequenceEqual(next));

            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(nextBytes);
            return result;
        }
    }

    return false; //if not found return false

}
```

Comment: thanks this has seemed to speed them up thank you.
just ran some bench-marking, seems to be better with smaller buffer sizes
[graph](https://snipboard.io/afrlUO.jpg)

Comment: Obviously smaller buffers are going to be better. Otherwise you are still doing compares exponentially. The plus side to this version is that it avoids all of the array allocations. Your version constructs a bunch of extra arrays. The total with this version is two (the ones passed in to the function) I've made an edit that uses `ArrayPool` for your `nextBytes`

Comment: does that speed it up?